# utf-8: How to recover from missing bit?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings)

> If the byte stream is subject to corruption then some encodings recover better than others. UTF-8 and UTF-EBCDIC are best in this regard as they can always resynchronize at the start of the next code point;
>
> ...
>
> UTF-16 and UTF-32 will handle corrupt (altered) bytes by resynchronizing on the next good code point, but an odd number of lost or spurious byte (octet)s will garble all following text

I don't quite understand why UTF-8 works better than UTF-16 when corruption happens. What does "odd number" mean? Does it mean `1` in `0101010111101`(bytes stream)?

In addition, Can I say that UTF-16's recovery performance is as good as UTF-8 when no odd number of lost or spurious byte (octet) occur?

Could anyone give some point at how the system work to recover from bit error when using UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: I've never understood how error detection or correction or recovery at the character encoding level is useful. Errors occur in transmission and storage and those systems do those functions very well. Perhaps I've just had the luxury of working on platforms that support robust and reliable data services. (Same would apply to being able to index into a string at an arbitrary point and then advance to the next leading code unit. What text processing would require that?)

Comment: It quite clearly says "odd number of bytes (octets)" if you parse it for a bit. This isn't strictly true for UTF-16, either, if the corruption happens to occur in a 4-byte surrogate pair.

Answer (score 1):

This documentation quote refers to recovering the stream after having missing some code points, not correcting the characters that went bad during transmission.

And what it means is simply that: if you miss one or more byte in an utf-8 stream, as soon as the next byte is the beginning of a new code point (usually a character), you can resume your text from there.

In utf-16, all characters are 2 bytes long, and if you miss a single byte  then all subsequent bytes will be misplaced, and without further, higher level, correction, no other code-point will be correct for that stream.

For visualizing that, in Python3 interactive mode we could do:

```
In [19]: a = "Resumé for mr. Fernando"

In [20]: b = a.encode("utf-8"); b = b[:3] + b[4:] 

In [21]: print (b.decode("utf-8"))
Resmé for mr. Fernando

In [22]: b = a.encode("utf-16"); b = b[:10] + b[11:] 

In [23]: print (b.decode("utf-16", errors="replace"))
Resu 昀漀爀 洀爀⸀ 䘀攀爀渀愀渀搀漀�
```

(The slicing notation used in Python for those unfamiliar means `[<begin (inclusive)>: <end (exclusive)>]` as positions. Any parameter left blank is assumed to be the beginning or end of the sliced sequence)

And why "odd" should be obvious at this point: if you miss an even number of bytes, the decoding system will still try to decode at character boundaries - with an odd number, all character boundaries will be incorrect

Answer (score 1):

The magic hides in the structure of the encoding. In UTF-8 structure, all the starting byte of a UTF-8 encoded bytes cannot be misreplace by the byte that is not the starting byte. However, thing is not true in UTF-16.

UTF-8 structure
[image: UTF-8 structure]
Let's simulate how a magic machine that receiving UTF-8 encoded bytes as input and outputing code points works when one byte missed in a 3-byte long UTF-8 encoded bytes.

Say, the UTF-8 encoded bytes from two characters `一二` is `e4b880`(`一`) and `e4ba8c`(`二`). Now the machine reads `e4`, which is `11100100`, knowing that the following code point is a 3-byte long code point. Unfortunately, the following byte `b8`is missed. Next,`80` is read. Then, the first byte of `二` is read, which is `e4`. However, `e4` doesn't fit the rule right: When it comes to 3-byte long code point, byte 3 need to start with `10` according to the table above. Now the machine knows some bytes are missing and the code point is broken. It will try to look around to find the right decode starting point. Obviously, the next byte `ba` is not a good start because it doesn't fit any of the byte 1 in the table above. Then it will look back, finding that the previous byte `e4` is exaclty a good start byte to decode.

In UTF-16, a byte can be misreplaced by the byte that is not the starting byte because of UTF-16 have no way to tell whether it's a starting byte or not.